# jquery.dataTables.min.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I try to use ajax on DataTable, but i got this error..
Here i explain my code:

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tblEmployee').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                url: '/Employee/GetEmployees',
                dataSrc: ''
            },
            "columns": [
                { '': 'sEmpName' },
                { '': 'sGender' }
            ]
        });
    });
```

JSON Return:

```
[{"sEmpName":"Andi","sGender":"Man"},{"sEmpName":"Mark Will","sGender":"Women"},{"sEmpName":"Edward","sGender":"Man"}]
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tblEmployee" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sEmpName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sGender)
                </th>                    
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>
```

I've already read this document https://datatables.net/manual/ajax, but still get error..

Comment: https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sAjaxDataProp refer this - Since your response is just an array you need to use sAjaxDataProp to tell DataTables this fact - set it to an empty string (see the docs). Source : https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11901/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-jquery-datatables-js-1918

Comment: could you take a look to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahaa821j/) and let me know?

Comment: Thanks @Pat for your page suggestion, it works as well.. I will create an answer for this post.. :)

Comment: Ah sorry @pat im forget that.. XD
Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggestion from this source: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11901/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-jquery-datatables-js-1918

I changed my script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tblEmployee').DataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": '/Employee/GetEmployees',
            "sAjaxDataProp": "",
            "aoColumns": [
                 { "mDataProp": "sEmpName" },
                 { "mDataProp": "sGender" }
            ]
        });
    });
```

It works as well. Thank you.. :)

Note:
i used jQuery 3.1.0 and DataTables 1.10.12